# IUS not pulling latest PHP packages

Tags: linux, php, redhat, yum

I have a RHEL 7 64 bit machine that that IUS installed on it.  We are trying to get the latest hotfix version of php 7.1.  The version I am trying to download is 7.1.22, and we are on 7.1.21.  I have cleaned our cache with `yum clean all` and then rebuilt it using `yum makecache`.

Here is the IUS webpage - https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/7/x86_64/repoview/letter_p.group.html

I have installed the RPM with IUS installed, and enabled the IUS repositories.

```
[ius-archive]
name=IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch - Archive
#baseurl=https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/archive/Redhat/7/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.iuscommunity.org/mirrorlist?repo=ius-el7-archive&arch=$basearch&protocol=http
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/IUS-COMMUNITY-GPG-KEY
```

However when I do a yum upgrade on any of the php packages that need to be updated (even if I do something like `yum upgrade php71u`), I get - `No packages marked for update`.

Here is a snapshot of the packages on the server -

```
[root@myserver yum.repos.d]# rpm -qa | grep php71u
php71u-bcmath-7.1.21-1.ius.el7.x86_64
php71u-pdo-7.1.21-1.ius.el7.x86_64
php71u-tidy-7.1.21-1.ius.el7.x86_64
php71u-xml-7.1.21-1.ius.el7.x86_64
php71u-mcrypt-7.1.21-1.ius.el7.x86_64
php71u-xmlrpc-7.1.21-1.ius.el7.x86_64
php71u-json-7.1.21-1.ius.el7.x86_64
php71u-dba-7.1.21-1.ius.el7.x86_64
php71u-common-7.1.21-1.ius.el7.x86_64
php71u-ldap-7.1.21-1.ius.el7.x86_64
php71u-pecl-igbinary-2.0.5-2.ius.el7.x86_64
php71u-devel-7.1.21-1.ius.el7.x86_64
php71u-opcache-7.1.21-1.ius.el7.x86_64
php71u-cli-7.1.21-1.ius.el7.x86_64
```

However when I run a `yum update php71u-cli`, it tells me `No packages marked for update`.  However, on the IUS stable site, the package is on version 7.1.22 (which is what I want to update to).  https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/7/x86_64/repoview/php71u-cli.html.

This problem is replicated for each php package that I try to update to version 7.1.22.  When I try to do a yum install of that specific version, it gives me the same error, and when I do a `yum --showduplicates list php71u-cli` I dont see the expected version inside of the list.

How can I get the 7.1.22 hotfix from IUS?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the issue.  The IUS rpm that I downloaded from their site and installed doesn't include "stable" by default, it includes "archive", "dev" and "testing".  After I changed the baseurl in one of the yum repositories and did a `yum clean all` / `service httpd graceful` it worked as expected.  Its very strange that IUS doesn't install "stable" by default.

This is what I changed the yum config to -

```
[ius-testing]
name=IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch - Testing
baseurl=https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/7/x86_64/
#mirrorlist=https://mirrors.iuscommunity.org/mirrorlist?repo=ius-el7-testing&arch=$basearch&protocol=http
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/IUS-COMMUNITY-GPG-KEY
```

Comment: The ius-release package absolutely enables the stable repo by default.  You or someone else must have disabled that repo locally on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your local yum metadata, which tells among other things what packages are in a repository, is cached locally and only updated periodically. You can remove the cache to force it to be updated:

```
yum clean metadata
```

After that point, yum will download fresh metadata on the next attempt to install or update packages.

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, one of the steps I did when troubleshooting yesterday was a `yum clean all`, and it still didn't find the required php update package.  I ran the `yum clean metadata` that you posted as well command as well and got the same result today.  Do you have any other ideas?